# Fill VBA UserForm TextBox with variable cells based on TextBox Name

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a set of TextBoxes in an UserForm and want to fill them with data in Excel.

The TextBoxes are named like: "TextBoxXY". The X corresponds for the column number and the Y for the row number.

For example: 

TextBoxA13 need to have the value of cell A3

TextBoxA35 need to have the value of cell C5

How do I do this in VBA?

I tried something like this, but this isn't working. I see it first has to work every Y for X=1, then every Y for X=2.

```
    Dim X As Long
    Dim Y As Long
    For X = 1 To 10
    For Y = 1 To 10

    With Controls("TextBoxA" & X & Y)
    .Value = Cells(3 + X, 9 + Y)
    End With
    Next Y
    Next X
```

Comment: Hi Steffie. I was more than happy to answer your previous question today because you showed that you had at least tried something. It's important because otherwise we feel like we're just doing your work for you, rather than helping. So... what have you tried?

Comment: How do you differentiate between K1 and A11?

Comment: BTW: If you are trying to display worksheet data on a userform then I strongly suggest you use a listbox, rather than tons of textboxes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this situation I really need textboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Code tested against your example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Ctrl As Control

    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls

        If TypeName(Ctrl) = "TextBox" Then

            If Left(Ctrl.Name, 8) = "TextBoxA" Then

                Dim Col As Integer, Rw As Integer
                Col = Mid(Ctrl.Name, 9, 1)
                Rw = Mid(Ctrl.Name, 10, 1)

                Ctrl.Value = Cells(Rw, Col).Value

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

TextBoxes are named

```
TextBoxA11
TextBoxA12
TextBoxA13
```

respectively

[image]

Comment: The line Ctrl.Value = Cells(Rw, Col).Value will "fail" in case the cell contains an ERROR-Value https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb211091(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: if it solved your issue, please mark as answered so others know moving forward @Steffie